# Why isn't my Pandas 'apply' function referencing multiple columns working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have some problems with the Pandas apply function, when using multiple columns with the following dataframe

```
df = DataFrame ({'a' : np.random.randn(6),
                 'b' : ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
                 'c' : np.random.randn(6)})
```

and the following function

```
def my_test(a, b):
    return a % b
```

When I try to apply this function with :

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_test(row[a], row[c]), axis=1)
```

I get the error message:

```
NameError: ("global name 'a' is not defined", u'occurred at index 0')
```

I do not understand this message, I defined the name properly.

I would highly appreciate any help on this issue

Update

Thanks for your help. I made indeed some syntax mistakes with the code, the index should be put ''. However I still get the same issue using a more complex function such as:

```
def my_test(a):
    cum_diff = 0
    for ix in df.index():
        cum_diff = cum_diff + (a - df['a'][ix])
    return cum_diff
```

Comment: Avoid using `apply` as much as possible. If you're not sure you need to use it, you probably don't. I recommend taking a look at [When should I ever want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/4909087).

Comment: This is just about syntax errors referencing a dataframe column, and why do functions need arguments. As to your second question, the function `my_test(a)` doesn't know what `df` is since it wasn't passed in as an argument (unless `df` is supposed to be a global, which would be terrible practice). You need to pass all the values you'll need inside a function as arguments (preferably in order), otherwise how else would the function know where `df` comes from? Also, it's bad practice to program in a namespace littered with global variables, you won't catch errors like this.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

Seems you forgot the `''` of your string.

```
In [43]: df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_test(row['a'], row['c']), axis=1)

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
                    a    b         c     Value
          0 -1.674308  foo  0.343801  0.044698
          1 -2.163236  bar -2.046438 -0.116798
          2 -0.199115  foo -0.458050 -0.199115
          3  0.918646  bar -0.007185 -0.001006
          4  1.336830  foo  0.534292  0.268245
          5  0.976844  bar -0.773630 -0.570417
```

BTW, in my opinion, following way is more elegant:

```
In [53]: def my_test2(row):
....:     return row['a'] % row['c']
....:     

In [54]: df['Value'] = df.apply(my_test2, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, You are right I forgot the ''. However I have still the same issue with a more complex function. I would highly appreciate your help with that. Thanks

Comment: @Andy following [53-54] allow you to apply more complex functions.

Comment: @Andy you can define your complex function like the In[53] way.

Comment: do all apply strategies perform the same? I'm new to pandas and have always found apply slightly enigmatic but your strategy in [53-54] is easy for me to understand (and hopefully remember) ... on a large table is it as quick as the other form of apply presented?

Comment: Why is it that creating a separate method is considered more elegant - even for tiny methods. I have been doing significant projects in python for 7 years but will likely never be considered a `pythonista` due to some perspectives including this one.

Comment: `axis=1` is important here

Answer (score 34):

If you just want to compute (column a) % (column b), you don't need `apply`, just do it directly:

```
In [7]: df['a'] % df['c']                                                                                                                                                        
Out[7]: 
0   -1.132022                                                                                                                                                                    
1   -0.939493                                                                                                                                                                    
2    0.201931                                                                                                                                                                    
3    0.511374                                                                                                                                                                    
4   -0.694647                                                                                                                                                                    
5   -0.023486                                                                                                                                                                    
Name: a
```

Comment: I know, it is just an example to show my problem in applying a function to multiple columns

Answer (score 18):

Let's say we want to apply a function add5 to columns 'a' and 'b' of DataFrame df

```
def add5(x):
    return x+5

df[['a', 'b']].apply(add5)
```

Comment: I am getting following error while trying your code snippet. 
TypeError: ('must be str, not int', 'occurred at index b')
can you please look into that.

Comment: The column b of your dataframe is a string type or object type column, it should be an integer column to be added with a number.

Comment: Wouldn't the changes only apply after assignment?

Answer (score 11):

All of the suggestions above work, but if you want your computations to by more efficient, you should take advantage of numpy vector operations [(as pointed out here)](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame ({'a' : np.random.randn(6),
             'b' : ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
             'c' : np.random.randn(6)})
```

Example 1:  looping with `pandas.apply()`:

```
%%timeit
def my_test2(row):
    return row['a'] % row['c']

df['Value'] = df.apply(my_test2, axis=1)
```

> The slowest run took 7.49 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 1000 loops, best of
>   3: 481 µs per loop

Example 2:  vectorize using `pandas.apply()`:

```
%%timeit
df['a'] % df['c']
```

> The slowest run took 458.85 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 10000 loops, best of
>   3: 70.9 µs per loop

Example 3:  vectorize using numpy arrays:

```
%%timeit
df['a'].values % df['c'].values
```

> The slowest run took 7.98 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 100000 loops, best
>   of 3: 6.39 µs per loop

So vectorizing using numpy arrays improved the speed by almost two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Results change even more dramatically for big numbers, e.g. replacing 6 with 10K, I get 248 ms, 332 µs, 263 µs respectively. So both vectorized solutions are much closer to each other, but the non-vectorized solution is 1000 times slower. (tested on python-3.7)

Answer (score 3):

This is same as the previous solution but I have defined the function in df.apply itself:

```
df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a']%row['c'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have given the comparison of all three discussed above.

**Using values**

```
%timeit df['value'] = df['a'].values % df['c'].values
```

139 µs ± 1.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

**Without values**

```
%timeit df['value'] = df['a']%df['c']
```

216 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**Apply function**

```
%timeit df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a']%row['c'], axis=1)
```

474 µs ± 5.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)