# Mapping a few numerical columns into a new columns of tuples in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For `object` data I can map two columns into a third, (`object`) column of tuples

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["A","b"], ["A", "a"],["B","b"]])
>>> df
   0  1
0  A  b
1  A  a
2  B  b

>>> df.apply(lambda row: (row[0], row[1]), axis=1)
0    (A, b)
1    (A, a)
2    (B, b)
dtype: object
```

(see also [Pandas: How to use apply function to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns)).

However, when I try to do the same thing with numerical columns

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,2], [10, 1],[20,2]])
df2.apply(lambda row: (row[0], row[1]), axis=1)
     0     1
0    10    2
1    10    1
2    20    2
```

so instead of a series of pairs (i.e. `[(10,2), (10,1), (20,2)]`) I get a `DataFrame`.

How can I force `pandas` to actually get a series of pairs? (Preferably, doing it nicer than converting to string and then parsing.)

Comment: The former behaviour appears to be a bug (and is fixed in the development branch, but not in 0.12).

Comment: Why do you need a `Series` of `tuple`s? Having it as two columns in a `DataFrame` is *much* more flexible IMHO.

Comment: @PhillipCloud It is not for further storing - just I need a series where I have pairs (so I can series.value_counts() to make statistic for pairs - e.g. to calculate mutual information).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend this, but you *can* force it:

```
In [11]: df2.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([(row[0], row[1])]), axis=1)
Out[11]:
         0
0  (10, 2)
1  (10, 1)
2  (20, 2)
```

### Please don't do this.

Two columns will give you much better performance, flexibility and ease of later analysis.

#### Just to update with the OP's experience:

What was wanted was to count the occurrences of each [0, 1] pair.

In Series they could use the [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method (with the column from the above result). However, the same result could be achieved using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and found to be 300 times faster (for OP):

```
df2.groupby([0, 1]).size()
```

*It's worth emphasising (again) that `[11]` has to create a Series object and a tuple instance for each row, which is a **huge** overhead compared to that of groupby.*

Comment: @PhillipCloud I was wondering if the discouragement should be much much larger...

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks. It is not for further analysis - just I want to calculate distribution of pairs (e.g. to calculate mutual information). Another option for me is to use `collections.Counter` and `map(lambda x, y: (x, y), df[0], df[1])` as in this use case I don't need index anymore; I was curious if I can manage within `pandas`.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal With the column of tuples above, you can use `.value_counts()`. However, it'll be more efficient to use groupby on the original DataFrame: `df2.groupby([0, 1]).size()`

Comment: @AndyHayden Would it be more efficient (for my data there are typically ~100 other columns and I just want calculate mutual information between two columns)?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal %timeit and see, my guess is yes, but would be interested to see either way! :)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I make it around 40 times faster for a toy example of 1000 rows and 100 columns.

Comment: @AndyHayden For my data, `(3992, 77)`, `groupby` is 300x faster (sic!). Thanks! (It wasn't a bottleneck, but still great - now it is only 2.7ms.)