# Pandas apply to dateframe produces '<built-in method values of ...'

Tags: python, pandas, apply, geojson, shapely

I'm trying to build a [GeoJSON object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples). My input is a csv with an address column, a lat column, and a lon column. I then created Shapely points out of the coordinates , buffer them out by a given radius, and get the dictionary of coordinates via the mapping option- so far, so good. Then, after referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns), I wrote the following function to get a Series of dictionaries:

`def make_geojson(row):
        return {'geometry':row['geom'], 'properties':{'address':row['address']}}`

and I applied it thusly:

```
data['new_output'] = data.apply(make_geojson, axis=1)
```

My resulting column is full of these: `<built-in method values of dict object at 0x10...`

The weirdest part is, when I directly call the function (i.e. `make_geojson(data.loc[0])` I do in fact get the dictionary I'm expecting. Perhaps even weirder is that, when I call the functions I'm getting from the apply (e.g. `data.output[0]()`, `data.loc[0]['output']()`) I get the equivalent of the following list:
    `[data.loc[0]['geom'], {'address':data.loc[0]['address']}]`, i.e. the values (but not the keys) of the dictionary I'm trying to get.

For those of you playing along at home, here's a toy example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping
import pandas as pd

def make_geojson(row):
    return {'geometry':row['geom'], 'properties':{'address':row['address']}}

data = pd.DataFrame([{'address':'BS', 'lat':34.017, 'lon':-117.959}, {'address':'BS2', 'lat':33.989, 'lon':-118.291}])
data['point'] = map(Point, zip(data['lon'], data['lat']))
data['buffer'] = data['point'].apply(lambda x: x.buffer(.1))
data['geom'] = data.buffer.apply(mapping)
data['output'] = data.apply(make_geojson, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: As always, things are very likely to go off the rails when you start putting non-scalar elements in Series and DataFrames; this is happening because a branch is taken assuming that pandas can call `someobj.values` and get the values of an NDFrame but since you've given it a dictionary it's instead getting the dictionary method.  What's your final goal?

Comment: I'm just trying to get a geojson object (or a python dictionary I can dump to geojson). That's gonna look like [this](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples).

Comment: @dsm I am following the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13337376/1599229), but my equivalent of `f()` is returning a `dict`. Same issue as this question. Yet it's possible to store a `dict` in a `DataFrame`. I don't know quite what you mean by "a branch is taken" -- does that mean: `apply` with a returned `dict` is not possible at all? Is there another way to operate on each row while storing the `dict` result in a new column?

Comment: @bahmait The issue is that the values method on the dictionary is overwriting the values method on the NDFrame. Instead of applying whatever function you're calling to a DataFrame, map it to lists of the columns you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, DSM, for pointing that out. Lesson learned: pandas is not good for arbitrary Python objects

So this is what I wound up doing:

```
temp = zip(list(data.geom), list(data.address))
output = map(lambda x: {'geometry': x[0], 'properties':{'address':x[1]}}, temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got to this post because I ran into a similar issue, but when running a PySpark DataFrame instead of Pandas.

In case someone ends up here, like myself, I'll explain how I fixed it for a PySpark DataFrame.

The reason why I was getting the error (`built-in method of Row object`, in my case), was because my field name `count` was colliding with the inherited method count from python tuples (as seen [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13179)).

The solution was simply change the name of the field to something like `my_count` and it worked fine.