# Create Boolean Columns in Pandas Dataframe using Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a network trace dataset, and have loaded the initial data into a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

[image: Initial Dataframe]

I have created a python dict with common port numbers and applications names like

```
port_dict = {80: 'http', 20: 'ftp', 21: 'ftp'}
```

and I want to modify my dataframe by adding additional columns whose names will be the unique values of the `ports_dict` and if either of `sport` or `dport` contains the relevant key, the newly added column should have a value `True`, `False` otherwise, like this:

[image: Modified Dataframe]

In the above picture, the column `https` should have `True` as the sport is `443`.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Looks like a nice usecase for  a multi column apply. Just write a function with your mapping dict. Apply this function to slice of your columns. Finish. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out.  `Series.map` should be a faster way to look up values from the dictionary.   `pandas.get_dummies` turns a single column of data into columns for each distinct value as 1s / 0s, which I'm converting into a bool, and compare with or (`|`) to get whether the service was on either port.

```
service = pd.get_dummies(df['sport'].map(port_dict)).astype(bool) | pd.get_dummies(df['sport'].map(port_dict)).astype(bool)

df[services.columns] = services

In [166]: df.head()
Out[166]: 
   dport  sport    ftp   http
0      1      1  False  False
1     80      2  False  False
2      2     80  False   True
3      3     20   True  False
4      1      1  False  False
```

Comment: So this way can I deal with the nominal values of the port numbers too??

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest that you will simply have a `service` column, then if the `sport` or `dport` are in the `port_dict` keys then the value will be written in the `service` column:

```
port_dict = {80: 'http', 20: 'ftp', 21: 'ftp'}

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'sport':[1, 2, 80, 20], 'dport':[1, 80, 2, 3]})

for i in df.index:
    found_service = port_dict.get(df.ix[i, 'sport'], False) or port_dict.get(df.ix[i, 'dport'], False)
    df.at[i, 'service'] = found_service

# a small example dataframe
>>       dport  sport service
      0      1      1    False
      1     80      2    http
      2      2     80    http
      3      3     20     ftp
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works, but because of the looping and since my dataset contains around 47121615 rows, it takes an awful lot of time. Can you suggest me ways to optimise this?

Comment: Try this way instear of the `for` loop. It will create 2 new columns, `sservice` and `dservice`:              

`df[['dservice', 'sservice']] = df[['dport','sport']].applymap(port_dict.get)`