# Learning to use map in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, map-function

I want to model this excel formula for two dataframe columns, df1 and df2, row by row:

```
=IF(df1 > df2; df2; df2 - df1)
```

I know this can be done with **map** in Python, but don't know how. I can do it with a for loop and an if-else statement, but it makes my code harder to read.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually a job for `mask` or `where`.

```
df2.mask(df1 <= df2, df2 - df1)
```

Or,

```
df2.where(df1 > df2, df2 - df1)
```

More generally, this is from numpy:

```
np.where(df1 > df2, df2, df2 - df1)
```

---

For these sample DataFrames:

```
df1
Out: 
          A         B         C
0  0.446762 -0.435975  0.109038
1 -0.729108  3.670354  0.761667
2 -0.244370 -0.256956 -1.831161

df2
Out: 
          A         B         C
0 -1.192108  0.074628 -0.087634
1 -0.324098  0.698479 -0.287896
2  1.807863 -2.564992 -2.361296
```

The first two yield

```
          A         B         C
0 -1.192108  0.510603 -0.087634
1  0.405010  0.698479 -0.287896
2  2.052233 -2.564992 -2.361296
```

`np.where` returns a numpy array so you might need to convert it back to a DataFrame:

```
array([[-1.19210755,  0.51060284, -0.08763422],
       [ 0.40500973,  0.69847936, -0.28789618],
       [ 2.05223294, -2.56499239, -2.36129577]])
```

Comment: Should be the other way around; `df2.where(df1 > df2, df2 - df1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is create a new column that is a function of the columns `df1` and `df2` in the way in which you describe.  (If not correct me if I'm wrong.)

Then this is a case of using the `apply` function, something you should get to know well for using pandas.  Assume your dataframe is called `df` and your new column will be called `df3`.  Then:

```
df3 = df.apply(lambda x : x["df2"] if x["df1"] > x["df2"] else x["df2"] - x["df1"], axis=1)
```

There's a whole lot of stuff going on here, especially because you are [applying to the whole `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (usually you see `apply` used with just one column as input - technically, [`apply` to a `Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) - and the syntax is simpler.)  The `axis=1` is required to explain to pandas that this should be applied to sets of columns (you would think that would be the default but it is not, so always remember to use it when you are applying to the whole `DataFrame`.)  The `lambda` is used to access the two columns and carry out the function; here, `x` is abstractly any row of the `DataFrame` itself.  Basically, this is a way of doing a vectorized mapping.  It is one of the most common tools in pandas and you'll find yourself using it a lot.

A good basic `apply` tutorial is [here](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes.html), showing mostly applications to a single column (with the simpler syntax I mentioned, where you don't need `axis=1`.)  [Here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns) is another example of applying to multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Very easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through

```
df2 - df1*(df2 > df1)
```

For example,

```
In [51]: df1
Out[51]: 
0    0.588922
1    0.876270
2    0.276917
3    0.521514
dtype: float64

In [52]: df2
Out[52]: 
0    0.628234
1    0.492461
2    0.782199
3    0.759758
dtype: float64

In [53]: df2 - df1*(df2 > df1)
Out[53]: 
0    0.039312
1    0.492461
2    0.505282
3    0.238245
dtype: float64
```

Performance-wise, the three solutions posted so far behave as follows on a (100000, 2)-shaped DataFrame:

```
In [124]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [125]: df['df1'] = np.random.uniform(size=10**5)

In [126]: df['df2'] = np.random.uniform(size=10**5)

In [127]: df1 = df.df1

In [128]: df2 = df.df2

In [130]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x : x["df2"] if x["df1"] > x["df2"] else x["df2"] - x["df1"], axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.97 s per loop

In [131]: %timeit df2.where(df1 > df2, df2 - df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

In [132]: %timeit df2 - df1*(df2 > df1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop
```