# Why my code works (filtering a data-frame with a function)?

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, I have created a function with input of lat Lon in order to filter ships not entering a particular zone.

```
check_devaiation_notInZone(LAT, LON)
```

It takes two inputs and return True if ships not enter a particular zone.

Secondly, I got data on many ships with Lat in one header and Lon in another header in CSV format. So, I need to take data from two column into the function and create another column to store the output of the function.

After I looked at [Pandas: How to use apply function to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns). I found the solution `df1['deviation'] = df1.apply(lambda row: check_devaiation_notInZone(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), axis = 1)`

But I have no idea why it works. Can anyone explain the things inside the apply()?

Comment: For each row in `df1`, run `check_devaiation_notInZone` with values from the `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns, and save the result in the `deviation` column.  `axis = 1` means to apply the function over each row instead of each column.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function is just like a normal function but it has no name and can be used only in the place where it is defined.

```
lambda row: check_devaiation_notInZone(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
```

is the same as:

```
def anyname(row):
    return check_devaiation_notInZone(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
```

So in the apply you just call another function `check_devaiation_notInZone` with the parameters `row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']`.

Comment: And why row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'] can refer to the columns? The function will take "row" as input, but what exactly is the input in this code: df1['deviation'] = df1.apply(lambda row: check_devaiation_notInZone(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), axis = 1)