# How to loop through each index and calculate order statistic of each group

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by

I have a dataframe called `dta_filter`, the main variable of interest is `LogEarn for AgeInDays in [20, 25)`. There are 16 groups for `YRSSCH` ranging from 0, 1, ..., 15. An excerpt of the dataframe is shown in the pictures below.

What I aim to do is the following. I will use the Index (0, 0.1) observation in the `output` dataframe (picture shown below) as an example. First, I need to extract the value corresponding to 0 from the `counts` array (picture shown below). In this case, the value is 758. Next, I need to calculate the expression j = floor(758*0.1-1.96) where floor() denotes the floor function. Finally, I need to calculate the j-th order statistic of `LogEarn for AgeInDays in [20, 25)` for the group corresponding to `YRSSCH=0` in the dataframe `dta_filter` and output this value in a new column in the dataframe `output` (and in the same row as (0, 0.1)) and call the column `Lower Bound`.

I need to do the above for all the Index values in `output`. So, to further illustrate, for example, for the (1, 0.5) index in `output`. The expression j will be j = floor(202*0.5-1.96) since 202 is the value corresponding to 1 in the `counts` array and it is multiplied by 0.5 because 0.5 is the second number in (1, 0.5). Then, I need to calculate the j-th order statistic of `LogEarn for AgeInDays in [20, 25)` for the group corresponding to `YRSSCH=1` (note, the group is dictated by the first number in (1, 0.5)) in the dataframe `dta_filter` and then output this value in the `Lower Bound` column in the dataframe `output` and in the same row as (1, 0.5).

My code below only does this one at a time. For example, for the (0, 0.1) index:

```
k=math.floor(counts[0]*0.1-l)-1

x=dta_filter[(dta.YRSSCH==0)][['LogEarn for AgeInDays in [20, 25)']]

x=x['LogEarn for AgeInDays in [20, 25)'].tolist()

lower_bound=np.partition(np.asarray(x), k)[k]
```

Note: In the above code, I have a -1 in the expression for k since the code `np.partition(np.asarray(x), k)[k]` indexes the first order statistic from 0 rather than from 1.

How can I do the above for all indices in `output`? I am only a beginner in python, perhaps a loop might work?

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, if my question was not clear enough, please let me know and I will edit to further explain.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but I think you should look into pandas `apply`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns). Take note that depending if you want to apply across rows or columns, you'll need to set `axis` accordingly.