# Pandas combine columns on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I intend to combine columns of a Pandas DataFrame after `groupby`. I looked for options that I can use but none of them does what I'm looking for. The closest option was `.agg()` which performs on values of a column, however, I want to calculate a statistic of all `features` for every given groupbyed row.

I am looking for something like this:

```
dataset.groupby(['company', 'team']).combine(new_cols=['features_mean'], to_combine=['feature 1':'feature 2'], funcs=[np.mean], axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `mean`:

```
dataset['new measure'] = dataset.loc[:, 'Feature 1':'Feature 12'].mean(axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'Feature 1':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'Feature 2':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'Feature 3':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'Feature 4':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

#print (dataset)

dataset['new measure'] = dataset.loc[:, 'Feature 1':'Feature 4'].mean(axis=1)
print (dataset)
   A  F  Feature 1  Feature 2  Feature 3  Feature 4  new measure
0  a  a          4          7          1          5         4.25
1  b  a          5          8          3          3         4.75
2  c  a          4          9          5          6         6.00
3  d  b          5          4          7          9         6.25
4  e  b          5          2          1          2         2.50
5  f  b          4          3          0          4         2.75
```

Comment: Worth to note that for some reason this approach runs much faster than ```apply```!

Comment: @NovinShahroudi - because `apply` are loops under the hood ;)

Comment: Looked up at the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L4774). right, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I don't even need to use `groupby`. I can simply use `apply`:

```
dataset['new measure'] = dataset.apply(lambda r: r['Feature 1':'Feature 12'].mean(), axis=1)
```

[This post helped!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns)

However, it runs slow due to using of `for` loop in the [implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L4774).