# Apply a function to modify multiple columns with if else logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to write a function with if-else logic which will modify two columns in my data frame. But its not working. Following is my function

```
def get_comment_status(df):
    if df['address'] == 'NY':
        df['comment'] = 'call tomorrow'
        df['selection_status'] = 'interview scheduled'
        return df['comment'] 
        return df['selection_status']
    else:
        df['comment'] = 'Dont call'
        df['selection_status'] = 'application rejected'
        return df['comment']
        return df['selection_status']
```

and then execute the function as :

```
df[['comment', 'selection_status']] = df.apply(get_comment_status, axis = 1)
```

But I am getting error. What am I doing wrong ? My guess is probably the df.apply() syntax is wrong

Error Message:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 
>   KeyError:('address', 'occurred at index 0')

sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['NY', 'CA', 'NJ', 'NY', 'WS', 'OR', 'OR'],
               'name1': ['john', 'mayer', 'dylan', 'bob', 'mary', 'jake', 'rob'],
               'name2': ['mayer', 'dylan', 'mayer', 'bob', 'bob', 'tim', 'ben'],
               'comment': ['n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a'],
               'score': [90, 8, 88, 72, 34, 95, 50],
               'selection_status': ['inprogress', 'inprogress', 'inprogress', 'inprogress', 'inprogress', 'inprogress', 'inprogress']})
```

I have also thought of using lambda function but it doesnt work as I was trying to assign value to 'comment' and 'selection_status' column using '='

Note: I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/how-do-i-use-pandas-apply-function-to-multiple-columns) which is similar by title but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: It's useful if you list the error as well

Comment: Look at your return statements: only the first one in each branch gets executed. You'll need to return something else, essentially both values at the same time.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: Note that `.apply` doesn't work on a dataframe, but on a row. For your code, it doesn't matter, but the naming of your variable `df` in your function implies you're thinking incorrectly about apply, which will cause confusion later on.

Comment: @9769953 - that was very useful note. gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do is not very consistent with Pandas philosophy. Also, `apply` is a very inefficient function. You probably should use Numpy `where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['comment'] = np.where(df['address'] == 'NY',
                  'call tomorrow', 'Dont call')
df['selection_status'] = np.where(df['address'] == 'NY',
                           'interview scheduled', 'application rejected')
```

Or boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['address'] == 'NY', ['comment', 'selection_status']] \
         = 'call tomorrow', 'interview scheduled'
df.loc[df['address'] != 'NY', ['comment', 'selection_status']] \
         = 'Dont call', 'application rejected'
```

Comment: This is what I understand so far - If I need to return more than one column, writing a function is not useful . I have used df.loc method before - but here I wanted to return both column at the same time instead of separately dealing with them using np.where or df.loc . But I guess that wasnt right approach.

Comment: @singularity2047, Pandas is based on series arrays (columns). Updating each series individually in a vectorised fashion will usually be faster than updating them together via `pd.DataFrame.apply` (which is just a very inefficient loop).

Answer (score 2):

You *should* use `numpy.where` as per [DyZ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50826806/9209546). A principal benefit of Pandas is vectorised computations. However, below I'll show you how you *would* use `pd.DataFrame.apply`. Points to note:

- Row data feeds your function *one row at a time*, not the entire dataframe in one go. Therefore, you should name arguments accordingly.
- Two `return` statements in a function will not work. A function stops when it reaches `return`.
- Instead, you need to return a list of results, then use `pd.Series.values.tolist` to unpack.

Here's a working example.

```
def get_comment_status(row):
    if row['address'] == 'NY':
        return ['call tomorrow', 'interview scheduled']
    else:
        return ['Dont call', 'application rejected']

df[['comment', 'selection_status']] = df.apply(get_comment_status, axis=1).values.tolist()

print(df)

  address  name1  name2        comment  score      selection_status
0      NY   john  mayer  call tomorrow     90   interview scheduled
1      CA  mayer  dylan      Dont call      8  application rejected
2      NJ  dylan  mayer      Dont call     88  application rejected
3      NY    bob    bob  call tomorrow     72   interview scheduled
4      WS   mary    bob      Dont call     34  application rejected
5      OR   jake    tim      Dont call     95  application rejected
6      OR    rob    ben      Dont call     50  application rejected
```

Comment: This is immensely helpful for me. Although I will lean towards np.where() from now on, I'd still like to learn different methods of doing same thing.