# python pandas changing several columns in dataframe based on one condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python and Pandas.  I worked with SAS.  In SAS I can use IF statement with "Do; End;" to update values of several columns based on one condition.
I tried np.where() clause but it updates only one column.  The "apply(function, ...)" also updates only one column.  Positioning extra update statement inside the function body didn't help.

Suggestions?

Comment: can u show a sample of your df(input and output), and the code you tried?

Comment: I want to implement: if (<condition>): df['col1'] = .... ; df[col2 ] = ... ; etc. . I know who to do it for each column separately with apply or np.where()

Answer (score 0):

You can select which columns you want to alter, then use .apply():

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 
                   'b':[4,5,6]})

    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6


df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: x+1)

    a   b
0   2   5
1   3   6
2   4   7
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/how-do-i-use-pandas-apply-function-to-multiple-columns) may help:

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I can apply lambda to multiple columns.  However, It is very simplistic case.   I want to implement:  if (<condition>):  df['col1'] = .... ; df[col2 ] = ... ; etc.  .  Yours

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = np.where(df[col] == your_condition, value_if, value_else)
```

eg:

```
   a  b
0  0  2
1  2  0
2  1  1
3  2  0

for col in df:
    df[col] = np.where(df[col]==0,12, df[col])
```

Output:

```
   a   b
0 12   2
1  2  12
2  1   1
3  2  12
```

Or if you want apply the condition only on some columns, select them in the `for loop`:

```
for col in ['a','b']:
```

or just in this way:

```
df[['a','b']] = np.where(df[['a','b']]==0,12, df[['a','b']])
```

Comment: To follow your example, I want  df['a'] to be 12 as u did and df['b'] 25 instead of 12.

Comment: Then you can do so: df[['a','b']] = np.where(df[['a','b']]==0,[12,25], df[['a','b']])

Comment: Thanks Joe, I got it

Comment: You are welcome, please consider to accept the answer if It helped you :)