# passing dataframe to a function in python

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have written a `function` in python , but I am passing `string` to a `function` as a `parameter`, but I have a excel file that is Dataframe which has many rows now i want to process each row of a column as a `string` .How do i do that ?

I have written the following `function` which takes the string as a input no wi want o pass dataframe to the `function`, how do i do that?

```
def pre_process(utterance):
    utterance = remove_name(utterance)
    utterance = text_in_next_line_after_dot(utterance)
    utterance = convert_num_to_words(utterance)
    utterance = remove_stop_phrase(utterance)
    utterance = remove_character(utterance)
    utterance = remove_blank_lines(utterance)
return utterance.strip()
```

Dataframe looks like this

```
id         Utterance
1    my name is cyley . I am at post91
2    after 24 hours you need to send the email
3    there interaction id is 123456
4   he is studying at masters school
```

I have this kind of dataframe. I want to using utterance column as a string in the above function

Comment: just look for the `apply` function. see it working here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/why-isnt-my-pandas-apply-function-referencing-multiple-columns-working

Comment: i TRIED THIS BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING

Comment: okay, if you present a sample data (similar with what you are working with) and what you expect it to be with your python code/function, we could try to see there is a way we can improve on it.

Comment: @MEdwin I have updated the question, have added the sample data . I just  want to know how to I pass the whole data to my function pre_process . asmy function takes string as input

Comment: Doesn't map work in this example? your_df['Utterance_preprocessed']=your_df['Utterance'].map(pre_process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a mockup. basically you are updating a dataframe column with the logic in the function (`remove_numbers`: this remove all numbers from the utterance column). Let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4],
                  'Utterance': [
                      'my name is cyley . I am at post91', 
                      'after 24 hours you need to send the email', 
                      ' there interaction id is 123456', 
                      'he is studying at masters school']})
def remove_numbers(s):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', '', s)



def pre_process():
    df['Utterance'] = df['Utterance'].apply(remove_numbers)
    #utterance = text_in_next_line_after_dot(utterance)
    #utterance = convert_num_to_words(utterance)
    #utterance = remove_stop_phrase(utterance)
    #utterance = remove_character(utterance)
    #utterance = remove_blank_lines(utterance)
    return None

pre_process()

df
```

result below:

```
Utterance   id
0   my name is cyley . I am at post 1
1   after hours you need to send the email  2
2   there interaction id is 3
3   he is studying at masters school    4
```

Comment: can we do this using iterrows?

Comment: yes, that is possible too. if you show what you have done, we can fine tune. Check out  also `df.itertuples`.